# Imports from public folder Nextjs in typescript give error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, next.js

I am trying to import files using regular import and with the custom absolute paths in Nextjs using typescript.
For some reason I keep getting an error that the module cannot be found but my IDE is able to link the file when I click on it. Also, when its a regular javascript file, instead of typescript, it works fine and files are imported.

For now im using // @ts-ignore and it works, but I wonder if there is a better way to solve this error.

My tsconfig:

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/components/*"],
      "#/*": ["public/assets/images/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "public/**/*",
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try remove `baseUrl` and `paths` from tsconfig

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the path of the import.

If you have a `baseUrl` of `“.”`, the path would be `...from '/public/...'`. instead of `...from './public/...'`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).